# why does npm tries to install phantomjs?

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

I can't find a solution: I just set up a new Linux distro on my pi (raspian) and wanted to install those packages with one npm command:

> npm install telegraf blocktrail-sdk http request cookie-parser express-ipfilter googleapis express body-parser cron firebase-admin

After a few seconds I see that npm tries to install a package called phantomjs and ends up with this error message:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130

> phantomjs@1.9.20 install /home/pi/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Unexpected platform or architecture: linux/arm
It seems there is no binary available for your platform/architecture
Try to install PhantomJS globally
```

Now the weird thing is, that when I try to install these packages one by one:

> npm install telegraf ... npm install blocktrail-sdk and the other ones

it does not need to install phantomjs as a dependency. But why does it try to install it? What am I missing?

Any help would be really great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `phantomjs` package is a sub-dependency of the `blocktrail-sdk` package you are installing.

```
$ npm ls phantomjs
`-- blocktrail-sdk@3.0.14
  `-- html-pdf@1.0.0
    `-- phantomjs@1.9.20
```

The [issue](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/433) is that `phantomjs` can't find a binary for Linux/ARM platforms.

A workaround could be to clone the `blocktrail-sdk` repo, remove `html-pdf` from the `dependencies` field in the `package.json`, and then install it locally: `npm install "../path/to/blocktrail-sdk"`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I remove it as a dependency I would have to remove it from the whole sdk.